# How can i change color of an item at center position of a ListView

Tags: listview, flutter

I'm using ListView to display list of Text, and when it reaches center of list view, need to change its style.

Comment: can you add some code. i guess you can do that by changing the style when the list scrolls to  a particular index

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i know that an element is at center of list view

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if((items.length/2).floor() == index){

              return Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('${items[index]}asdas'),
                ),
              );
            }else{
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${items[index]}'),
              );
            }
          },
    )
```